# Setting getSheetbyName according to cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create a button that will take data from one sheet and place it in another sheet, where the other sheet is determined by the value in a cell on a primary sheet. I have the button working when my script says the name of a sheet, but I cannot seem to understand how I can make the destination dependent on the value in another cell. In my code, I am hoping that the value found in cell Q4 of our "Dash" Sheet can determine the getSheetByName as we have sheets for each month of the year.

```
function BP3CallTab() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Ready to Submit 3-Call Audit?.',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    copyFunction ();
  }

    function copyFunction () {
      var inputRange =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A9:AG11");
      var inputValues = inputRange.getValues();
      var outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('2').getRange("A17:AG19").setValues(inputValues);
    }

  if (result ==ui.Button.NO) {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No Changes Made.');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like this:

```
var shname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dash").getRange("Q4").getValue()
```